# Kubuntu 22.10 Grub won't update, syntax error

Tags: grub2, updates, kubuntu

When attempting to update grub, I run into the same issue which prevents the update process from going through:

```
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-26-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
Syntax error at line 179
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
```

I attempted to debug the file myself, but I was unable to determine the proper syntax for the specific error report. I also attempted to remove and reinstall grub, but any attempt to alter grub gives me the same error shown above. The aforementioned error also prevents me from updating the system or installing any new packages. Not sure what could have caused this behavior outside of not updating for a few days, since I have not made any manual changes to the grub files.

The below link lists the contents of the grub.cfg.new file, which hopefully someone can help shed some light on the issue:
https://pastebin.com/hcFxrwLD

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi
 
if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi
 
export menuentry_id_option
 
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi
 
function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}
 
if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi
 
if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 0,0,0; then
  clear
fi
 
color_normal=white/black
 
if [ -e ${prefix}/themes/kubuntu-logo/theme.txt ]; then
  insmod png
  theme=${prefix}/themes/kubuntu-logo/theme.txt
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if [ ${grub_platform} != pc ]; then
      set linux_gfx_mode=keep
    elif hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-29-generic root=UUID=abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791 ro  <other_params>... amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffffffff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-29-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.19.0-29-generic-advanced-abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.19.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-29-generic root=UUID=abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791 ro  <other_params>... amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffffffff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.19.0-29-generic-recovery-abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.19.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-29-generic root=UUID=abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-28-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.19.0-28-generic-advanced-abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.19.0-28-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-28-generic root=UUID=abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791 ro  <other_params>... amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffffffff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-28-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-28-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.19.0-28-generic-recovery-abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.19.0-28-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-28-generic root=UUID=abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-28-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-26-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.19.0-26-generic-advanced-abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.19.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-26-generic root=UUID=abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791 ro  <other_params>... amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xffffffff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-26-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-26-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.19.0-26-generic-recovery-abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt2'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.19.0-26-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-26-generic root=UUID=abc7033c-9aa2-467f-96e8-c89db2323791 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-26-generic
    }
}
 
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
 
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
 
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: As it says line 179, do you really have this? "<other_params>... "  That is also on other lines, so from /etc/default/grub. Remove that in grub & update again.

Comment: After applying this fix, grub updated once again with zero issues. What a fantastic fix! You are a wizard for applying this. I need to setup proper backups so I can walk back unexpected changes like these.